# how to cut image horizontally based on white regions

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am preparing an image for `tesseract` to `ocr`. What I have done so far is converting my image to the following:

[Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clV7z.jpg)

[image: original image]

What I basically want is to cut the image to horizontal portions based on the white regions. So like so:

[image: desired behavior]

**What I most care about are the text area in the left side and the middle one.**

[image: desired behavior 2]

The problem if I only pick left region is that I can't find a way to pick also the ones in the middle without deleting some parts.

The other problem that I faced is if I give `tesseract` all the regions (I have successfully already extracted every region that contains text) is that it gave me rubbish since the pic has both Latin and none latin language.

Another important thing is that there is no predefined size, so assuming the size in this picture is standard is wrong.

**To recapitulate: how to cut image horizontally based on white regions**

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html I think it is looking for black lines by default but you can easily invert your image.

Comment: @Zev good point, but before that the OP wants to know where to draw those lines.

Comment: @MimirLind Is it possible to add the original image as well?

Comment: I am trying with the link provided with Zev.  That's correct @Jeru, I need first to know where to draw lines. The original image is my id card. I edit it a little bit to hide my personal details, I hope I didn't disturb it.

Comment: @MimirLind Well enough. I am trying out a different approach. One that doesn't involve drawing lines. I will share it once I am done

Comment: Alright, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up the documentation to see if I could use anything. And YES I came across an interesting property called the **extent** of a contour from [THIS PAGE](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/d32/tutorial_py_contour_properties.html).

The extent of a contour is defined as the ration of *area of the contour* by *area of the bounding rectangle of that contour*. So the more closer this value is to 1 the more the contour resembles a rectangle.

For the image given by you it does not detect the words that look like Arabic. But it would work if some morphological operation is done prior to this.

**Code:**

```
path = 'C:/Users/Desktop/Stack/contour/'
im = cv2.imread(path + 'lic.png')

#--- resized because the image was to big ---
im = cv2.resize(im, (0, 0), fx = 0.5, fy = 0.5)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret2, th2 = cv2.threshold(imgray, 0, 255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

im2 = im.copy()
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th2, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
count = 0

#--- It all begins here ---
for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        rect_area = w * h
        extent = float(area) / rect_area
        if (extent > 0.5) and (area > 100):      #--- there were some very small rectangular regions hence I used the area criterion ---
            count+=1
            cv2.drawContours(im2, [cnt], 0, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow(path + 'contoursdate.jpg', im2)

print('Number of possible words : {}'.format(count))
```

**Result:**

[image]

In this case I have just drawn the contours. You on the other hand, can crop these regions by fitting a bounding rectangle and feed them individually to an OCR engine.

Comment: I don't want arabic, if it's possible to eliminate it, do you know how to proceed?

Comment: You can try varying the `extent` parameter in `if (extent > 0.5) and (area > 100):`

Answer (score 2):

You can play with the parameters to increase or decrease the number of lines. I followed [this guide](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

Loading and inverting the image:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('lic.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = 255 - img
```

Getting the edges:

```
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,50,150,apertureSize = 5)
minLineLength = 10
maxLineGap = 30
```

Finding the lines with a Probabilistic Hough Transform:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges,.7,np.pi/180, 100,minLineLength,maxLineGap)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        if x2-x1 == 0:
            continue
```

Checking that the slope is between -45 degrees and 45 degrees (you can adjust as needed):

```
        dy = (y2 - y1) 
        dx = (x2 -x1)
        if -1 < dy/dx < 1:
            cv2.line(img,(x1 + dx*-100,y1 + dy*-100),(x2 + dx*100,y2 + dy*100),(0,255,0),2)


cv2.imshow("image: " + str(len(lines)) , img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cv2.imwrite('houghlines3.jpg',img)
```

Which produced this image:

[image]